# Printing different language characters in psql

Tags: postgresql, utf-8, character-encoding, postgresql-12

I want to store multiple languages at the same column. First i'm creating db and tables.

```
CREATE DATABASE dbname ENCODING 'UTF8'
```

I'm saving the data succesfully, but when i want to print it with a SELECT query, i get this error using psql.

```
ERROR:  character with byte sequence 0xd9 0x84 in encoding "UTF8" has no equivalent in encoding "WIN1254"
```

So WIN1254 is Turkish which have different characters like ç, ş, ü... But i don't get this error only when i exclude Arabic, so the problem is not Turkish but Arabic. How can i solve this? Maybe i should do something while creating the db. Also while i'm printing, it doesn't print Turkish characters succesfully, just putting wrong characters.

Comment: You can set client encoding to utf8 as well PQsetClientEncoding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `psql` session, set the client encoding to match server encoding:

```
SET client_encoding TO 'UTF8';
```

---

Find `server_encoding` like so:

```
SHOW server_encoding;
```

For example:

```
psql <whatever>
=> SELECT * FROM table_foo;
ERROR:  character with byte sequence 0xef 0xbf 0xbd in encoding "UTF8" has no equivalent in encoding "LATIN9"
=> SHOW server_encoding;
 server_encoding 
-----------------
 UTF8
(1 row)
=> SET client_encoding TO 'UTF8';
SET
=> select * from table_foo;
-- Now OK
```

**SEE ALSO:**

PostgreSQL: Documentation: 23.3. Character Set Support: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/multibyte.html

Answer (score 1):

If your application or your client should display characters from different languages, they have to use a client encoding in which these characters are defined.

Arabic characters are not defined in WIN1254, so you have to use a different encoding. Typically, one would use UTF-8 or one of the UTF-16 encodings for that. Since PostgreSQL does not support UTF-16, UTF-8 is the way to go.

Since you are using Windows, matters may be more complicated, since there is no support for UTF-8 on the command line.